# Python(Celery) : signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, celery, tensorflow

Добрый день товарищи. 
В прокекте мы юзаем celery , и сегодня появилась вот такая ошибочка

```
4/19/2017 6:49:13 PM[2017-04-19 15:49:13,575: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: prophet_message_filtering[c7a081bf-e7de-44d3-a120-6d345faf3553]
4/19/2017 6:49:19 PM[2017-04-19 15:49:19,308: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'PoolWorker-1' pid:23 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
4/19/2017 6:49:19 PM[2017-04-19 15:49:19,332: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
4/19/2017 6:49:19 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/19/2017 6:49:19 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1224, in mark_as_worker_lost
4/19/2017 6:49:19 PM    human_status(exitcode)),
4/19/2017 6:49:19 PMbilliard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

Хар. машины

```
4 Physical Cores @ 3.4 GHz 
(1 × E3-1240 v3)

32 GB of DDR3 RAM 
(2 × 16 GB)

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (with KVM) (4.4.0)
```

Контейнер `root@****:/code/agent# uname -a
Linux 896ee86d4ee1 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016
x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Запускаем все внутри докер контенеров

Транспортный протоколо RabbitMQ

Бекенд брокер Redis

**UPD_1**
Проблема была в модуле tensorflow, после отключения модуля все заработало норм, теперь осталось понять **почему.**

Comment: что значит "после отключения модуля"? вы его перестали импортировать?

Comment: @rusnasonov нет перестали использовать его . Вовремя выполнения вылетала ошибка . Кто-то из наших наковырял в гугле что проблема в нашем процесоре. Но это все в тиории